# the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, truststore

I am trying to <strike>retrieve an SSL certificate</strike> and to call a soap webservice via that but getting stuck due to below issue

I tried all the solutions provided over stack overflow but it's not working at all..

Please let me know what is the solution of this problem, I am stuck badly...

```
Context:   WSWS3713E: Connection to the remote host xxx.xx.com:443 failed
Received the following error:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
```

Comment: What exactly is the point of adding a lot of relevant information to your question and then deleting it?

Answer (score -2):

It looks like your server is returning an empty certificate. You should check, for example, with your browser if there really is a certificate behind this URL you are calling (click on the lock near just next to the URL in the address bar).
You say you tried all solutions, but you're not telling which ones.
You can run your client with this jvm options to make it more verbose : -Djavax.net.debug=ssl ; come back with the trace and we'll look at it.

Comment: There is no such thing as an empty certificate. If there was no certificate there would have been a different exception.

Comment: This is normally because the path to the keystore is incorrect or the keystore is missing.